# Interval-matching PeriodIndex with DatetimeIndex during merge

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Given the below DataFrames, I'd like to add series 'bar' from `df_other2` into `df2`, so that the period of `df2` (which I understand as an interval) "matches" the datetime index (not an interval) of df_other2 (also called "period", but is really a datetime). The matching criteria should be that `df_other2.period` is within `df2`'s period (i.e. date is within the interval).

I was hoping that defining the target index as `PeriodIndex` and the source index as `DatetimeIndex` would be sufficient to do the matching, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What alternatives do I have to get this to work?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'period': PeriodIndex(['2012-01', '2012-02', '2012-03'], dtype='int64', freq='M'), 'foo': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> df2 = df.set_index('period')
>>> df2
         foo    x
period           
2012-01    1  NaN
2012-02    2  NaN
2012-03    3  NaN
>>> df_other = pd.DataFrame({'period': [datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1), datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 3), datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 10)], 'bar': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
>>> df_other2 = df_other.set_index('period')
>>> df_other2
           bar
period        
2012-01-01   a
2012-02-03   b
2012-01-10   c
>>> df2['x'] = df_other['bar']
>>> df2
         foo    x
period           
2012-01    1  NaN   # expected x='a' as '2012-1-1' is part of this period
2012-02    2  NaN   # expected x='b'
2012-03    3  NaN   # expected x='c'
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to align all `df_other2.period` with `df2.period` (and make them `DatetimeIndex`) and merge as usual.

I'll wait for better support in future releases:

> For regular time spans, pandas uses Period objects for scalar values
>   and PeriodIndex for sequences of spans. Better support for irregular
>   intervals with arbitrary start and end points are forth-coming in
>   future releases.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-stamps-vs-time-spans